# How oracle concurrently updates different rows within same data file

Tags: database, oracle11g

This tutorial [states](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/database_files.htm)

```
Database datafiles are physical files stored on disk
```

Now If I have a file on my computer, two processes cannot update the file simultaneously. But in Oracle if we update two rows that reside in the same data file, how can the two rows be updated simultaneously(concurrently)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in general it is not the separate sessions that write to the data files, it is a [DB Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/process.htm#CNCPT1250) process that changes the files on their behalf. Your sessions are changing data blocks held in memory -- in the [system global area](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/memory.htm#i10093) -- and writing changes to the [redo log buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/memory.htm#CNCPT1225).

When you commit the change, the data files themselves are not synchronously updated, but the commit cannot (in general) complete until the [log writer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/process.htm#CNCPT1251) process has written the outstanding change records to the redo log file. The writing of the changes and the commit record to the redo log file are enough to preserve the changes for recovery in the event of an instance crash -- the change to the dat files can follow asynchronously.

That is a gross over-simplification, and you can read more about Oracle architecture [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/toc.htm).